# How do i add the newly created post to the createdPost array of a user in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, crud

I am trying to build a social media platform, where user can post. When the user creates a post, it should be added to his createdPost list. How can i update this list?

This is the code i tried for updating the createdPost of the logged in user who just created a post -

```
export const addPost = async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        const newPost = new Post({userId : req.user.id, ...req.body}) 
        const savedPost = await newPost.save()
        console.log(savedPost._id)
        

        const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
            req.user.id,
            { $push: { createdPosts: savedPost._id } }, // Push the post ID to the array
            { new: true }
          );
        res.status(200).json(savedPost)
    }catch(err){
        next(err)
    }
}
```

this is my User Schema -

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String, 
        required: true, 
        unique: true
    }, 
    email: {
        type: String, 
        required: true, 
        unique: true
    }, 
    password: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    }, 
    createdPosts: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
    }, 
    likedPosts: {
        type: Array,
        default: [] // Using a function as the default value
    }, 
    bookmarkedPosts: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
    }
}, {timestamps: true})

export default mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

This is my Post schema -

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }, 
    title: {
        type: String, 
    }, 
    body: {
        type: String, 
    }, 
    tags: {
        type: [String], 
        default: []
    }, 
    likes: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
}, {timestamps: true})

export default mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema)
```

Comment: Well to start with, what _does_ your code do?

Comment: Does the new `Post` at least save? Is it just that it's `_id` isn't being added to the `User.createdPosts` array?  `await newPost.save()` works on it's own, you don't need to assign it's return value to a variable.